# After a particular grep match, I want to transfer all the following contents of the file to another file

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a text file containing the following lines:

```
This is the first line
Second line
I have a mac
Used to have windows
Comfortable with both
```

So now I want to grep "I have a mac", and move all the contents that follow, into a new file. How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crop everything from the line that contain *"I have a mac"* to the end of the file and write the output to a new file:

```bsh
sed -n '/I have a mac/,$ p' in-file > out-file
```

Remove everything from the line that contain *"I have a mac"* to the end of the file, make the changes in place of the file and create a backup copy of the original file:

```bsh
sed '/I have a mac/,$ d' in-file -i.bak
```

Use a variable that contain the string that you are searching for and conditionally execute the above two commands:

```bsh
SEARCH='I have a mac'
sed -n "/$SEARCH/,$ p" in-file > out-file && sed "/$SEARCH/,$ d" in-file -i.bak
```

Use grep to find (recursively) which file(s) contains the searched string and pass its name through pipe and `xargs` to the above commands ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958957/6543935)):

```bsh
export SEARCH='I have a mac'
grep -lr "$SEARCH" | xargs -L1 -I {} sh -c 'sed -n "/$SEARCH/,$ p" {} > {}.out && sed "/$SEARCH/,$ d" {} -i.bak'
```

Comment: To keep the matched line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5227429/6543935

Answer (score 1):

With `grep` you could use `-A` switch ( --> **A**fter Context) and `| tail -n+2` to start output with the second line to skip the match.

```bsh
grep -A $(wc -l < file) mac file | tail -n+2
```

But using `sed` is probably better for this case:

```bsh
sed '1,/mac/d' file
```

This **d**eletes everything from first line (1) until and including the matching line.

or you could use `awk`:

```bsh
awk '{if(m)print}/mac/{m=1}' file
```

will print a line when variable m is true `if(m)print}`, which is set to 1/true after the first match `/mac/{m=1}`.

---

"Transfer" `stdout` from a command to a file can be done with redirection: `> another_file`

```bsh
sed '1,/mac/d' file > another_file
#or
awk '{if(m)print}/mac/{m=1}' file > another_file
```